# robot rotation in place speed lower then minimum

Tags: navigation, move-base, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone
i am having a difficulty with my robot.
it navigates to a goal pretty well.
the thing is when it needs to rotate at the end to the orientation of the goal it doesnt seem to move.
when i look at the cmd_vel the robot receives a value of 0.457.. but the minimum value required for my robot to rotate is 0.55 this is also the value set in the base_local_planner_params so i dont get how can a value lower than the minimum is sent to the robot

please help me figure this one out

here is my base_local_planner_params file:

```
controller_frequency: 7.0
recovery_behavior_enabled: false
clearing_rotation_allowed: false

TrajectoryPlannerROS:
   max_vel_x: 0.4
   min_vel_x: 0.25
   max_rotational_vel: 0.79
   min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.55
   escape_vel: -0.3
   acc_lim_x: 0.05
   acc_lim_y: 0.5
   acc_lim_th: 0.07
   #min_rot_vel: 0.6
   #min_trans_vel: 0.6
   #max_trans_vel: 3.0
   #min_rotational_vel: 0.70

   holonomic_robot: false
   yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.5 # about 6 degrees
   xy_goal_tolerance: 0.8  # 5 cm
   latch_xy_goal_tolerance: true
   pdist_scale: 0.8
   gdist_scale: 0.4
   meter_scoring: true

   heading_lookahead: 0.325
   heading_scoring: false
   heading_scoring_timestep: 0.8
   occdist_scale: 0.1
   oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05
   publish_cost_grid_pc: false
   prune_plan: true

   sim_time: 2.0 
   # The amount of time to forward-simulate trajectories in seconds
   sim_granularity: 0.025 
   # The step size, in meters, to take between points on a given trajectory
   angular_sim_granularity: 0.025 
   # The step size, in radians, to take between angular samples on a given trajectory.
   vx_samples: 12  
   # The number of samples to use when exploring the x velocity space
   vtheta_samples: 20 
   # The number of samples to use when exploring the theta velocity space

   dwa: false
   simple_attractor: false
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224938/robot-rotation-in-place-speed-lower-then-minimum/) by [Dor](https://answers.ros.org/users/25256/dor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i was able to find in the base_local_planner package in the trajectory planner cpp file a minimum value that was set too low 0.4 and i changed it to 0.6 and than things worked out :)

---

Originally posted by [Dor](https://answers.ros.org/users/25256/dor/) with karma: 26 on 2016-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2018-08-03**:
Are you saying your solution was to change the source code? That seems like a hokey fix, the parameter should be loaded via the yaml file. I am seeing the same general behavior. Move base commands my robot to turn at 0.4 rad/s even though I set my minimum to be 0.9. Anyone have a more permanent fix?